# getSize to calculate and set width of input field

Tags: javascript, mootools, fluid

I have a div containing an input field and a submit button. The design needs to be completely fluid: the height of the submit button is set to height 100% (the parent div is also build in percentages).

I want to set the width of the input field: 100% - (width of submit button). I'm already using MooTools for some navigational purposes, I figured the getSize().x method could be used on the submit button and use this value to set the style of the input.

I'm just learning MooTools, who could set me in the right direction?

Comment: width: 100% in css, then follow the container/fluid grid system? no need to use js for this.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving the input field 70% width and the submit button 30%?

Indeed no js needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not very clear from my question: the submit button is a square image. By basing the size of this image on the width, it will not keep his correct ratio. By basing it on the height, it will keep a correct ratio but have a variable width. (being the same as the height of the parent div). That's why I want to get the X size of the submit, so the input field next to it can by calculated based on that variable X size.

Comment: If I understand correctly you should just set that image as the background image on the button, and use `background-size:cover`. You should really build a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) for clarify questions like this though.

Comment: Agree with Niels - fiddle would be useful.